# Concurrent Queue using Qt is deadlocking

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, queue

I am trying to create a concurrent queue with Qt's concurrent threading constructs.

```
#ifndef CONCURRENTQUEUE_H
#define CONCURRENTQUEUE_H
#include <QMutex>
#include <QWaitCondition>
#include <queue>

template<typename Data>
class ConcurrentQueue
{
private:
    std::queue<Data> the_queue;
    QMutex the_mutex;
    QWaitCondition the_condition_variable;
    bool closed;

public:

    void setClosed(bool state)
    {
        QMutexLocker locker(&the_mutex);
        closed = state;    
    }

    bool getClosed()
    {
        QMutexLocker locker(&the_mutex);
        return closed;    
    }

    void push(Data const& data)
    {
        QMutexLocker locker(&the_mutex);
        the_queue.push(data);
        the_condition_variable.wakeOne();    
    }

    bool empty()
    {
        QMutexLocker locker(&the_mutex);
        return the_queue.empty();    
    }

    bool try_pop(Data& popped_value)
    {
        QMutexLocker locker(&the_mutex);
        if(the_queue.empty())
        {
            return false;
        }
        popped_value = the_queue.front();
        the_queue.pop();
        return true;
    }

    void wait_and_pop(Data& popped_value)
    {
        QMutexLocker locker(&the_mutex);
        while(the_queue.empty())
        {
            the_condition_variable.wait(&the_mutex);
        }
        popped_value = the_queue.front();
        the_queue.pop();
        the_condition_variable.wakeOne();
    }

    //created to allow for a limited queue size
    void wait_and_push(Data const& data, const int max_size)
    {
        QMutexLocker locker(&the_mutex);
        while(the_queue.size() >= max_size)
        {
            the_condition_variable.wait(&the_mutex);
        }
        the_queue.push(data);
        the_condition_variable.wakeOne();
    }


};

#endif // CONCURRENTQUEUE_H
```

I have my producer thread using the wait_and_push method to push data into the queue, and I have been trying to get my consumer to read from the queue using try_pop

```
 while(!tiles->empty() || !tiles->getClosed())
{
             if(!tiles->try_pop(tile))
                    continue;
//do stuff with the tile
}
```

However, this deadlocks sometimes. The producer sets the closed boolean as a flag to the consumer threads that it is finished loading the queue. My consumer only has that as a way to know whether teh queue is being loaded, still in progress, or hasnt been started.

The reason the producer has a "wait_and_push" isntead of using the normal push is because I wanted to be able to make that thread block until some items had been processed to avoid eating up so much memory, and doing unnecessary disk I/O.

Can anyone point me to what is going wrong?

Comment: This doesn't help directly with your question but you might want to consider making the queue only responsible for thread safe access and move logic for throttling producing and consuming into the producing and consuming classes.

Comment: @Arnold Spence: It is not unusual to have built-in "throttling" that limits the queue size. It is a well-known idiom called *bounded blocking queue*. See http://drdobbs.com/cpp/184401814, http://zthread.sourceforge.net/html/classZThread_1_1BoundedQueue.html, http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html.

Comment: Try to use QSemaphore. It can be better (more handy) than QWaitCondition for this task.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to add

```
the_condition_variable.wakeOne();
```

in `try_pop`.

If there will be multiple producers / consumers accessing your queue, you should have a separate `QWaitCondition` for producers and consumers, otherwise `wakeOne` might not wake the correct thread.

EDIT:

If there will be multiple producers / consumers, then you should have a `notFullCondvar`, and an `notEmptyCondvar`.

- The `try_pop` method wakes the `notFullCondvar`.
- The `wait_and_pop` method waits on the `notEmptyCondvar`, but wakes the `notFullCondvar`.
- The `push` method wakes the `notEmptyCondvar`.
- The `wait_and_push` method waits on the `notFullCondvar`, but wakes the `notEmptyCondvar`.

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: There is one producer, and multiple consumers. Are you saying that all of the "pop" methods should have a QWaitCondition, and the push methods should have a separate QWaitCondition?